# Elasticsearch sort settings on index giving strange results

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elk

I have an index set up like so:

```
PUT items
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "sort.field": ["popularity", "title_keyword"],
      "sort.order": ["desc", "asc"]
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 15,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      },
      "title_keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "popularity": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "visibility": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the following data:

```
POST items/_doc/1
{
  "title": "The Arbor",
  "popularity": 5,
  "title_keyword": "The Arbor",
  "visibility": "public"
}

POST items/_doc/2
{
  "title": "The Canon",
  "popularity": 10,
  "title_keyword": "The Canon",
  "visibility": "public"
}

POST items/_doc/3
{
  "title": "The Brew",
  "popularity": 15,
  "title_keyword": "The Brew",
  "visibility": "public"
}
```

I run this query on the data:

```
GET items/_search
{
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "the", 
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "visibility": "public"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": ["<mark>"],
    "post_tags": ["</mark>"], 
    "fields": {
      "title": {}
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to match the records correctly on the word `the` but the sorting does not seem to work.  I would expect it to be sorted by popularity as defined and the results would be `The Arbor`, `The Brew`, `The Canon` in that order but the results I get are as follows:

```
{
  "took" : 11,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.27381438,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "items",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.27381438,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "The Brew",
          "popularity" : 15,
          "title_keyword" : "The Brew",
          "visibility" : "public"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "title" : [
            "<mark>The</mark> Brew"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "items",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.26392496,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "The Arbor",
          "popularity" : 5,
          "title_keyword" : "The Arbor",
          "visibility" : "public"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "title" : [
            "<mark>The</mark> Arbor"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "items",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.26392496,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "The Canon",
          "popularity" : 10,
          "title_keyword" : "The Canon",
          "visibility" : "public"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "title" : [
            "<mark>The</mark> Canon"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does defining the sort fields and orders when creating the index, under the settings, automatically sort the results?  It seems to be sorting by score and not the popularity.  If I include the sort options in the query it gives me the correct results back:

```
GET items/_search
{
  "size": 3,
  "sort": [
    {
      "popularity": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "title_keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "the", 
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "visibility": "public"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": ["<mark>"],
    "post_tags": ["</mark>"], 
    "fields": {
      "title": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I read that including the sort in the query like this is inefficient and to include it in the settings.  Am I not doing something when creating the index to make it sort by popularity by default?  Does including the sort options in the query result in inefficient queries?  Or do I actually need to include it in every query?

Hopefully this makes sense!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index sorting defines how segments are sorted in a shard, this is not related to the sorting of search results. You can use a sorted index, if you often have searches that are sorted with the same criteria, then the index sort speeds up the search.

If your search has a different sort than the index or no sort at all, the index sort is not relevant.

Please see the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html) for index sorting and especially the part that [explains how index sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html#early-terminate) is used.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  I was misinterpreting the documentation.